# jQuery load function modified to include relevant scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

Ive been playing with the load, get, ajax and get scripts function.

The most appropriate to the majority of function where I intend to load in content on a page would be the load function. It is a simple and effective way of getting the relevant content from an associate page.

But since it does not include scripts and the new content does not respond to the pages ready. functions I was wondering if there was a simple enhancement we could make that would allow the scripts of the page to be refreshed to include loaded content.

Something like

```
function loadall(url,container){
$(container).load(url);
scritps.reset();
}
```

What would be the way of doing this.

Comment: The .load() function takes in a 'complete' callback function that executes when the content is loaded. The normal way to handle what you're asking is to call any init code in your page's scripts inside that callback. I'm not sure what you mean by refreshing the scripts to include the loaded content. Assuming you are using some modules that react to the page's DOM, you should look in the docs for those scripts to see how to trigger a re-scan or re-init.

Comment: Sounds like what I am looking for. Marvellous. Thanks...